# querySelector doesn't find elements after polymer-ready event

Tags: polymer

I have a custom element (let's call 'el-barto'). It is inside a template of another template.

Now. I can use querySelector `document.querySelector('el-barto')` to select it without any problems using chrome dev tools console.

But the same query returns nothing if done from js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() { document.querySelector('el-barto'); });
```

People said: add event listener for `polymer-ready` and so I did:

```
...
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    console.log('yey, poly is ready!');
    console.log(document.querySelector('el-barto'));
});
...
```

And this prints:

```
yey, poly is ready!
null
```

So I went ahead and set a timeout, just like this:

```
...
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    console.log('yey, poly is ready!');
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(document.querySelector('el-barto'));
    },100);
});
...
```

And what do you know?

```
yey, poly is ready!
<el-barto>...</el-barto>
```

(I've noticed, that timeout with less than 100 ms returns null for the query selector).

Now, I ain't gonna go around setting timeouts left and right.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Even more.

If I use query selector like:

```
document.querySelector('#main').content.querySelector('#sub-main').content.querySelector('#sub-sub-main').content.querySelector('el-barto')
```

it will work without setting a timeout. But the question is why after 100ms I can find 'el-barto' without this long query? My goal would be to find such elements without using those long query selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'polymer-ready'` event doesn't fire when everything is actually in the DOM. It only confirms that all elements that were present at the time of the page load have been imported and are upgraded. Further, just because the elements are upgraded does not actually mean that the DOM is fully manipulated (though often it is if you aren't doing too many complex things). This is especially true if your custom element dynamically adds to the DOM based on properties.

Querying the DOM too early is always a danger with any library or framework that manipulates the DOM. This is especially true if the library has a complex initialization process. If your additional scripting and/or elements requires that the `<el-barto>` be present, consider firing an event in `<el-barto>`s `domReady` function. This will bubble up the DOM through the ancestors, allowing you to ***know*** that the `<el-barto>` is upgraded and present (with its immediate children).

In whichever ancestor you choose, you can simply listen for your event with `addEventListener` and either add your query or, even better, get the `<el-barto>` from the event object.

```
Polymer('el-barto', {
    ... other el-barto code ...
    domReady: function() {
        this.fire('el-barto-ready');
    }
    ... other el-barto code ...
});
```

Anywhere else...

```
[ancestor].addEventListener('el-barto-ready', function() {
    console.log(document.querySelector('el-barto');
});
```

Comment: I'm scared. I'm scared, man. I fear for my code to end up riddled with these event listeners all over the place. But I don't think I have any over option.

Comment: Generally, having too many of these is not a good idea. One option is to find the thing that will definitely load last and make one event to listen to it. Another option is to make one ancestor listen for all necessary components and then notify the topmost element that everything is loaded. If neither of those will solve your problem, then I would consider rethinking some things.